# What's the point of this double casting?

Tags: c, casting

I found these conversions from `uint16_t` to `int32_t` here https://gist.github.com/mux2000/5a0db5be900ca8b7f2d528fb37968b38.

```
int32_t ac6 = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[AC6], 
        ac5 = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[AC5],
        mc = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[MC],
        md = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[MD];
```

`bmp180_cal_data` is an array of `uint16_t`. So, when converting from different sizes of unsigned to signed and viceversa, one should first cast to the size of the original value (`bmp180_cal_data[x]` in this case) and then cast to the new size.

Is that correct?, if it is, why?, if not, why did it cast twice?

Comment: The cast to `int32_t` is pointless.

Comment: "I found bad code on Github" No way! :) The whole project is overall sloppily written, with inconsistent style and indention, poor variable names and next to no comments. Also embedded system projects should always use stdint.h. I'd avoid using this code as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found these conversions from uint16_t to int32_t here https://gist.github.com/mux2000/5a0db5be900ca8b7f2d528fb37968b38.

```
int32_t ac6 = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[AC6], 
        ac5 = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[AC5],
        mc = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[MC],
        md = (int32_t)(int16_t)bmp180_cal_data[MD];
```

> `bmp180_cal_data` is an array of `uint16_t`. So, when converting from different sizes of unsigned to signed and viceversa, one should first cast to the size of the original value (`bmp180_cal_data[x]` in this case) and then cast to the new size.

- The first cast convert a 16bit integer (unsigned) into a `signed` 16 bit integer.
- The second cast converts (merely just extends the sign from 16 to 32 bit) copying the sign bit to the left until filling the upper 16bits of the number.  This cast is unnecessary, as the initialization code needs to convert the number into an `int32_t` (as the variable is declared so), but doesn't harm.

The reason for this cast is that automatic conversions made by the compiler will first extend the `unsigned` to 32 bits, then will reinterpret the MSB as a sign bit (this requires no sign extension) and results in no code (in two's complement architectures, in others things change), just to put `0` bits on the left and nothing more has to be done.  But again the second cast will be done automatically by the compiler.  It would have been necessary if the declaration stated variables to be `uint32_t` typed (in that case the number should have first be converted again to unsigned, then extended with zeros)

But all this code is *implementation dependent*, indeed if you are going to treat the bytes in `bmp180_cal_data` array as `signed` values, why not just declare them as `signed`?  in that case no casts would have been needed, because the automatic conversion just would have extended the sign from 8 bits to 32.

Just for the next time, consider this mnemotecnic rule: first bit extension is done, then the sign is considered.  But when truncating a number, things don't work this way, as you are losing bits, things don't happen easily if the number magnitude has to be truncated for this to work.  Sign is not preserved when dealing with bit truncation, and results can be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is trying to do the "right" thing when the value in `bmp180_cal_data` is higher than `INT16_MAX`, based on implementation-specific behavior. Casting that to `int16_t` is implementation-dependent in this case, but common behavior is to just interpret the bits in two's complement format, so it will wrap around to negative numbers (the inverse of how negative numbers are handled when converting signed to unsigned). Then it uses the second cast to extend this to 32 bits, which will keep the negative numbers.

If they cast directly to `int32_t`, the large 16-bit numbers would just keep their original values, since they fit in 32 bits, rather than becoming negative.

So if the original value is `65535`, this becomes `-1` when the double cast is used, but would stay `65535` with a single cast.

Comment: A single cast to `int16_t` would suffice for the wrapping, so this leaves the cast to `int32_t` unexplained. The `int16_t` will automatically be converted to the destination type, `int32_t`.

Comment: What do you people mean by "wrap around"? Sorry, I'm not an English native speaker.

Comment: @EmTor It's easier to explain with `int8_t` and `uint8_t`. The maximum value of the signed version is 127. If you have an unsigned value 128, and convert it to signed, it becomes `-127`. "wrap around" refers to clock arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The second cast isn't necessary, since it will be done automatically. I think it's there just to be explicit.

Comment: @Barmar: +128 wraps to −128, not −127.

Comment: Right, I got confused about which end has the extra number.

Answer (score 1):

The single cast of `(int16_t)` is useful to map the values above `INT16_MAX` to negative values (in a common implementation defined manner): [32,768 ... 65,535] to [-32,768 ... -1].

The cast of `(int32_t)` serves no purpose and makes the code [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#WET).  Functionality is well defined and the same with/without the `(int32_t)` cast.

Perhaps the code author simply did not realize that the `(int32_t)` cast was not needed?